# How do you select the specific line to read in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, streamreader

I was wondering if/how you can read a specific line in vb.net using a system.io.streamreader.

```
Dim streamreader as system.io.streamreader
streamreader.selectline(linenumber as int).read
streamreader.close()
```

Is this possible or is there a similiar function to this one?

Comment: not exist, read your file via **while** and put a counter

Comment: Text files are *streams*, you cannot know where a line starts and ends other than by reading them one by one until you reach the line you want.  It is very likely that you should not be storing data in text files when you find you need to start writing code like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `File.ReadAllLines` to read in the lines into an array, then just use the array to select the line.

```
Dim allLines As String() = File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
Dim lineTwo As String = allLines(1) '0-based index
```

Note that `ReadAllLines` will read the entire text file into memory but I assume this isn't a problem because, if it is, then I suggest you take an alternative approach to trying to jump to a specific line.

Answer (score 0):

`ReadLines` is pretty fast as it doesn't load everything in memory. It returns an `IEnumerable<string>` which allow you to skip to a line easily. Take this 5GB file:

```
var data = new string('A', 1022);
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"d:\text.txt"))
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 1024 * 1024 * 5; i++)
    {
        writer.WriteLine("{0} {1}", i, data);
    }
}

var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var line = File.ReadLines(@"d:\text.txt").Skip(704320).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
watch.Stop();

Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time: {0}", watch.Elapsed); // Elapsed time: 00:00:02.0507396
Console.WriteLine(line); // 704320 AAAAAA...
Console.ReadLine();
```